# Wet Hot American Summer movie and TV show question

Tags: wet-hot-american-summer

I have finished watching Wet Hot American Summer: First Day Of Camp and I have read that I should watch the movie before I watch the TV series as it's hard to understand certain things and references that relate to the movie.

So, should I watch the movie before season 2 starts and in order to have a better understanding of season 1?

I didn't quite understand the bizarreness of the show.

Comment: I'm afraid asking if the movie is "any good" or if you should "bother watching it" is entirely opinion-based and likely to be closed as such. Are you asking if the movie's story is relevant for the TV-show and vice-versa or what the best watching order for understanding the story would be and if one requires to have seen another? Because that might be on-topic here.

Comment: @TomCody I'll edit to be clearer.

Comment: IMO it's better to watch the movie first and then the TV series as the expansion of the character backgrounds/appearances is much funnier when you watch the TV series

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I watched the movie before the TV series and I've spoken to a colleague who like you watched the TV series first.

IMO whilst it is unncessary, it is much better to watch the movie first for the following reasons:

- It establishes all the characters and how they end up so the way the TV series expanded on the backgrounds and their movie situations is explained
- It's more interesting to see how the actors looked like and behaved in the earlier film and makes the TV series more interesting in seeing how they managed to create a TV series from this with so many, now more famous, stars
- A lot of the running props/gags/background stories are incidental in the movie, how they scripted the full story that leads to their current situation in the TV series is both surprising and far funnier IMO

So I'd suggest watching the movie and then re-watch the TV series, IMO the movie is not that brilliant. The way they made a brilliant TV series from the movie is the truly satisfying thing for me.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! This has helped with my decision a lot. :)

Answer (score 1):

To counter EdChum (not that that answer is wrong...it's good!) I watched the series first, then the movie.

I think it works equally as well. In fact, I enjoyed watching the movie afterwards to connect all the little in-jokes. (This is a bit like how Arrested Development is set up...lots of punchlines are exposed early, with the set-ups revealed later. Sort of a 'slow burn' type of pacing). In addition, since the series happens chronologically *before* the film, the timeline is preserved as well.

As for not understanding the bizarreness, I don't think the watching order will help with that. It's simply a somewhat bizarre comedy.

Comment: Thank you for your input! :D I am going to watch the film!